# How to search though a colums of data in access

Tags: ms-access

I have a large number of .csv files (all formatted in the same way) that I am trying to pull data from and summarize it in an access database. There are a few things I need to pull from the data that are written on different columns and rows.

For example: one column has all zeros unless there is a switch turned on. Then there is a non-zero value. I only want to find the first occurrence of that one non-zero value and then output a different value from the same row. (say the 0 to non-zero occurs in column 14 row 8, and the value I want is in column 2 row 8)

Comment: Yes, access can work with all the data. I need the found values put into another table that I would use as a summary table. Can this be done with a query?

Comment: ![Data](http://s5.photobucket.com/user/Robot551/media/Data.jpg.html)and ![Summary](http://s5.photobucket.com/user/Robot551/media/Summary.jpg.html)

Comment: I would look for the RF1 SV and when the value is non-zero I would return the step duration but only for the first change (from 0 to non-zero). and that would be stored under nitirdation time in the summary table the others have their own triggers but its much the same

Comment: "I only want to find the first occurrence [...]"  
Thats actually a problem with databases - entries have no inherent order. If you import (or link) data in Access and display the result, it usually looks as though the original order was maintained. But there is no guarantee: The order is undefined, the DBMS has control over it and can order it any way it likes. Thats also the reason why there are no commands like "*find the first occurence of*" in SQL. You *might* succeed if you automatically add an auto increment key during import in preserving the original order. But that is just a guess...